# org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub artifact not found

Tags: java, maven, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a project that is using these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.utils</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It seems that these dependencies are not available anymore.
Do you know any other versions of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WSO2 artifacts are not available on Maven Central. 
You need to add the following repository :

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>wso2-maven2-repository</id>
        <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```